# I'm using ActionMailer with Rails Devise. Confirmation emails are successfully sent to my outlook email but not to gmail or yahoo email acounts.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer with Rails Devise. Confirmation emails are successfully sent to my outlook email but not to gmail or yahoo email acounts.

## development.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
    :tls => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "[my_user_name]",
    :password => "[my_password]"
}
```

my correct email and password are used

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Note carefully that the email could be in the SPAM folders of yahoo and Gmail. Emails sent from development tent to go to SPAM in Gmail and Yahoo because of non-qualified source address.